# Error when defining a function in lua, corona sdk

Tags: function, sdk, lua, coronasdk

Please, help me figure out what is the problem in the code.
I am defining a function

```
local function goOnLesson()
   if date.hour==1  then
   index=1
   local subj=schToday[index]
   local text = display.newRetinaText("А сейчас у тебя: "..subj, 0, 0, native.systemFont, 70)
   text:setTextColor(128,64,0)
   text:setReferencePoint(display.CenterReferencePoint)
   localGroup:insert(text)
   end
end
```

And when I'm running it, everything is fine.

I reorganized the code and I don't need if block anymore

```
local function goOnLesson()
   index=1
   local subj=schToday[index]
   local text = display.newRetinaText("А сейчас у тебя: "..subj, 0, 0, native.systemFont, 70)
   text:setTextColor(128,64,0)
   text:setReferencePoint(display.CenterReferencePoint)
   localGroup:insert(text)
end
```

I just removed if-end block but now it doesn't work.
Please help :)

Comment: post the error which you get.

Comment: explain your question little bit briefly.

Comment: Director ERROR: Failed to execute function: 0x1013763e0( params ) function on 'screen-schedule'.
-----------------------

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error appears to be a generic message when there is a run-time error during the execution of Corona events. I found several references to the same issue (for example, [here](http://developer.coronalabs.com/forum/2011/12/13/director-errorfailed-execute-newparams-function-menu-where-my-object)).

It's possible that schToday doesn't have any elements, and your `subj` variable gets a nil value, which then fails on string concatenation. You original code probably "works" because it doesn't get into that section (your `day.hour == 1` condition returns "false" most of the time).

I suggest you doublecheck your code to make sure it works as you expect it to work.

Another thing to try is to localize your `index` variable. It's possible that you assign a value to it that breaks something in other parts of your program.